# A weird expression in c++ - what does this mean?

Tags: c++, expression

I've seen this code for finding a Minor of a matrix:

```
RegMatrix RegMatrix::Minor(const int row, const int col)const{
  //printf("minor(row=%i, col=%i), rows=%i, cols=%i\n", row, col, rows, cols);
 assert((row >= 0) && (row < numRow) && (col >= 0) && (col < numCol));

 RegMatrix result(numRow-1,numCol-1);

 // copy the content of the matrix to the minor, except the selected
    for (int r = 0; r < (numRow - (row >= numRow)); r++){
  for (int c = 0; c < (numCol - (col > numCol)); c++){
   //printf("r=%i, c=%i, value=%f, rr=%i, cc=%i \n", r, c, p[r-1][c-1], r - (r > row), c - (c > col));
   result.setElement(r - (r > row), c - (c > col),_matrix[r-1][c-1]);
  }
 }
     return result;
}
```

This is the first time I encounter a code line like this: r < (numRow - (row >= numRow)).

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(row >= numRow)` is a boolean expression. If `operator>=` has not been overloaded, it should evaluate to `true` if `row` is greater or equal to `numRow`, and to `false` otherwise. When casting this boolean to an integer for subtraction, it will become 1 if true, 0 else.

Comment: so, how does this code "ignores" the given row & col numbers in copying the values to the matrix? it's still a mysterious code to me...

Answer (score 1):

`(row >= numRow)` is a boolean expression, which when used like this gets converted to an `int`, with `true` becoming `1` and `false` becoming `0`

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat clearer way to express it might be:

`r < (row >= numRow ? numRow - 1 : numRow)`

Answer (score 0):

`row >= numRow` will return a boolean true or false, and that is the implicitly cast into an integer `0` or `1`. So what that does is basically same as:

```
r < (numRow - (row >= numRow ? 1 : 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

`row >= numRow` will return 1 if `row` is greater than or equal to numRow, otherwise 0.

Thus, the code line is equivalent to a function like this:

```
bool foo() { 
    if(row >= numRow)
       return r < numRow - 1;
    else
       return r < numRow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of using a comparison operator is either a `true` of `false` which when used as an integer is `1` or `0`.

`r < (numRow - (row >= numRow))`

is same as

`r < (numRow - 1)` if `(row >= numRow)`

else it is `r < numRow`

Answer (score 0):

As others have said before, it is just a `bool` expression that is cast into an `int` before substracting (it means: substract 1 if `row >= numRow`).

But I would add that it is quite absurd. You have already asserted that `row < numRow`, so `row >= numRow` would violate the preconditions for your function. And the same happens for `col > numCol` in the following line.